# How can I disable the drag handle on the desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui-snapping

Any idea how the ability to "drag" the desktop app can be turned off? I'm talking about the area in the top-middle of the screen that changes the mouse cursor when you hover over it. On metro apps it makes sense, but on the desktop more often than not I end up inadvertently dragging the desktop somewhere when trying to select icons.

Screenshot:

[image: 1]

If it can't be turned off for the desktop only, can it be disabled globally?

Comment: Please note, that the answers here do not work anymore with the latest updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/software-and-web-apps/how-to-make-windows-8-look-like-windows-7-50009546/) suggests that [Skip Metro Suite](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.33) would allow you to turn off the drag to close interface. I imagine it will set some registry key.

[image: Skip Metro Utility]

Comment: Not quite perfect, the "zone" is still there. However, clicking/dragging it no longer moves the desktop around. Good enough for me!

Comment: Doesn't work with Windows 8.1 for me

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly enough, **Classic Shell** is capable of doing this.
See below. (It's in the Classic Start settings, and you have to tick the **all settings** box too.)

The "Disable active corners: All" is what did the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"[MordernUI Tuner](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.223)" is by the same author as the mentioned Skip Metro Suite (WinAero), but purportedly works with Windows 8.1 (Update 1).

> ModernUI Tuner is my latest tweaker which allows you to change few hidden but very useful options of the fresh Windows 8.1 Feature Pack/Spring Update 1.

It includes specifics for tuning how apps are closed:

[image]

Comment: It had no effect on my Windows 8.1 update 1. I can grab the top from the very same distance. (Explorer did restart when I pressed the button.) Will try the other (top-voted) tool after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

[Start8 from Stardock](http://www.stardock.com/products/start8/) also has this capability when choosing the option :

`Settings > Desktop > Disable all Windows 8 hot corners when at the Desktop`

[image]